# Tutorial for a Tutorial in IOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7

I'm already finishing an app and I would like to make a tutorial embedded in the App, like those that appear as an overlay, explaining the functionality of every button, in the app until the user taps the screen.

Another option could be to show a tutorial the first time a user opens the app, but I don't know how to identify if is the first time a user opens the app.

Does anyone knows a good tutorial that shows how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you done any research on either option?

Comment: If your app requires an in-app tutorial, it is likely too confusing for the user. Instead, work to simplify the app.

Comment: do you really need tutorial for tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this link [HERE](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/). Its a tutorial for a tutorial you are trying to create using UIPageViewController.

and here is how you can detect the first time user loads the app:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // app already launched
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!